# Find Oldest Date in Current Month from List of Dates

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, date, web-scraping

**Background:** I'm writing a script in Python to help manage the paper usage at my company. I'm just scrapping the printer config pages and storing the Total amount of paper consumed for each printer in an SQL Database. The company we lease our printers from gives us a limit each month before we get charged extra, so I want to alert myself and my manager when/if we go over that limit.

The printer's config page only has the total amount consumed - there's no way to get the total amount for the current month from it.

I feel like I'm over-thinking this problem but I wanted to get some other thoughts on it.

**So here's the question:** If I have a list of timestamps from `strftime('%s','now')`(the unix epoch), how would I determine which date is the oldest one from the current month? I'd then want to subtract that from the current date to see if we're over the monthly limit.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) have a `start of month` modifier; use that as a filter.

To get the latest of those dates, order by the date, and take the first one:

```sql
SELECT name,
       (SELECT current_pages
        FROM printers
        WHERE name = names.name
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) -
       (SELECT current_pages
        FROM printers
        WHERE name = names.name
          AND timestamp < CAST(strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of month') AS INTEGER)
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS this_month_pages
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
      FROM printers) AS names;
```

Comment: This looks perfect, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what everything is doing. [This](http://imgur.com/j9aTuHY) is what my table looks like - can you revise it to work with that? Sorry if  that's asking too much(this is my first time using SQLLite so I'm new to everything).

Comment: Could I use this in a for loop that goes through the printer names, then limit these SELECTs to the specific name with a WHERE statment.. something like:

`SELECT (SELECT current_pages
        FROM printers 
        WHERE name like '%Downtown 24th Floor - Center%'
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) -
       (SELECT current_pages
        FROM printers
        WHERE date < CAST(strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of month') AS INTEGER) AND WHERE name like '%Downtown 24th Floor - Center%'
        ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS ThisMonthAmount;`

Comment: If the table structure matters, put it into the question.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM prints
where prints.timestamp between UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-11-01") and UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-12-01");
```

Which will get you all the prints printed in November.

EDIT: For your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM prints
where prints.timestamp between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

which will get current month's usages.

Comment: I adjusted your code to match my table, but I'm getting "no such function: NOW" when I try to run it.

`SELECT *
FROM printers
where printers.date between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());` is what I changed it to

Comment: This is not valid in SQLite.

Comment: Got it! 

`select * from printers where DATE(date, 'unixepoch') between date('now','start of month') and date('now') ORDER by date;` does the trick - thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually what I thought worked didn't... Still figuring it out

Comment: Matt T you'll need to convert the dates to UNIX. I dont know sqlite but something like:

select * from printers where DATE(date, 'unixepoch') between strftime('%s',date('now','start of month')) and strftime('%s','now') ORDER by date;

;